# Jumping content after $(document).ready() executed

Tags: jquery

This question is related to my previous question

[Vertical floating div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701591/vertical-floating-div)

So first when page is load floating div appeared in left:0, top:0 and than after some delay it is getting moved to the position according with logic defined in $(document).ready()

So the question is how to avoid such kind of behavior is there something i can do to avoid that?

Is there any way beautify load such kind of content, to display content only after $(document).ready()  or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `display:none` to the style of `<div>` in question (in your static CSS), switching to `display:block` from JS (`$('#divid').fadeIn()` or `$('#divid').show()` for example) as soon as it is ready.

Taking HTML/CSS from your previous question:

```
<div id="twitter-right-vrtical" style="position: fixed; bottom: 415px; right: 446px; display: none">
    <img src="/Content/themes/start/images/twitter.png" title=""/>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    //set new position
    $('#twitter-right-vrtical').css({'top' : newTop, 'left': newLeft}).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can use jquery "`.animate()`" to make moving more fancy